# Navigation drawer items click is not working on other activities

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to click on navigation drawer items but not working.
I made a **NavigationDrawerActivity** (by default: creating new project) and an **AriesActivity** (new activity). When I go with NavigationDrawerActivity, item click works. But when i go with AriesActivity, item clicks are not working.
Here I included **drawer icon** on AriesActivity, clicking on icon navigation drawer opens but item clicks are not working.

So the main question is How to handle clicks over navigation items on other activities by including drawer on other activities?

> Here's my AriesActivity code

```
  public class AriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar mtoolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_aries);

        //setting TOOLBAR on this activity(page)
        mtoolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle(null);


        //setting DRAWER on this activity(page)
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, mtoolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
   }
}
```

Comment: is this ur full class code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override this method (onNavigationItemSelected) Example :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
            finish();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity1.class));
            finish();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: In which activity I have to override this method?